# ATA Drive vs Flash Storage

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I am a student who is looking to buy a Macbook. My budget is 1200 USD.

I will be using it for programming mostly.

I came across 2 laptops:

```
13-inch MacBook Pro Item Price:$1,134.00
  Hardware
2.5GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz
8GB 1600MHz DDR3 SDRAM — 2x4GB
1TB Serial ATA Drive @ 5400 rpm
SuperDrive 8x (DVD±R DL/DVD±RW/CD-RW)
```

Air:

```
13-inch MacBook Air Item Price:$1,149.00    
Hardware
1.6GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 2.7GHz
Intel HD Graphics 6000
8GB 1600MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM
256GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
```

Macbook Pro seems like it has more processing speed & more storage. However, Air Model has a Flash storage.

How much difference does the Flash Storage make? Is it worth sacrificing on clock speed for flash storage?

Comment: Do you need iops or convenience?  If you don't need the high iops of flash storage then get the MacBook Pro and upgrade your 5400 RPM drive to a 1TB SSD for less than $400.  You won't notice the difference.

Comment: @Allan: This is exactly what I don't know. How much slower would the RPM drive be compared to flash storage? 1 sec diff in bootup. No problem. Huge difference while fetching files then flash storage makes more sense

Comment: A SSD will be about 50x faster on small files and random I/O.  Flash storage is connected to PCIe while the SSD is connected to the SATA controller.  Technically there is more speed with PCIe flash, but nothing you will notice.  Again, are you writing software that requires iops (meaning lots of disk reading/writing)?  The 5400 RPM drive is awful slow, but you can upgrade it to SSD easily.  The flash in the Air is extremely expensive.  Go MBP.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of programming you're going to do. Especially if you going to test the programs that you're developing.

Any of these "is it worth it" questions are going to be highly subjective.

I would think that an average programmer would value the SSD more than the extra CPU speed, as compiling/building involves a lot of small files which the SSD will handle faster than the ordinary hard drive. However, a RAM drive would be faster than either disk. So it depends on your setup.

Also remember that the MacBook Pro is a 2012 model compared to the 2015 MacBook Air, so you cannot compare the CPU as simply 2.5 Ghz vs. 1.6 Ghz. This could lead you to believe that the MacBook Pro has a CPU that is 56% faster than the MacBook Air - however benchmarks show that the CPU is really only about 4% faster. The GPU is also faster on the Air (Intel HD6000 vs. Intel HD4000).

Comment: A lot of Machine Learning in Python which will involve some serious number crunching

Comment: It's very hard to say anything one way or the other without knowing numbers. ML in Python can mean anything from first year students doing assignments on simple 1-digit OCR to something very advanced. It's unclear if the input data is a single 1 MB file, or a billion 100 byte files for example.

Comment: I don't know since I haven't started classes yet. Imagine a large dataset from kaggle. Anyways it is not going to be a billion 100 byte files. It should be something like 5-10 1MB files.

Comment: I don't know what kind of class you're taking, but to me it doesn't sound like it really requires "serious number crunching" as such. If it were me, I would definitely go for the SSD. Also remember that the MacBook Pro is really an old 2012 model, so you cannot compare the CPU as simple 2.5 Ghz vs. 1.6 Ghz. This could lead you to believe that the MacBook Pro has a CPU that is 56% faster than the MacBook Air - however benchmarks show that the CPU is really only about 4% faster. The GPU is also faster on the Air - so all in all, I would get the Air unless you have some very specific requirement

Comment: Alright thanks a lot @jksoegaard. The 56% , 4% analogy was helpful